# Outlook Conditional Impacting Gmail Webviewer

Tags: css, email, outlook

I have an email I'm building where I want an element to be visible in outlook, but invisible in every other email client.  The CSS I have is:

```
 .outlook { display:none; }
 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style type="text/css">
.outlook {display:block;}
</style>
 <![endif]-->
```

It appears to work on my iOS email client, android, thunderbird and most importantly Outlook.  But when I test in GMail (webmail client) - the image assigned the outlook class is still visible.  What am I missing?

-- edited to add --

Nope, that additional mso rule didn't work unfortunately.

Are there outlook specific rules as to what types of elements can have CSS applied to them?  I have this class being applied to an **img** tag.  Ought I place it on something else like the wrapping **td** tag maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually use to display elements **only** in Outlooks

```
<!--[if mso]>
<style type="text/css">
.outlook {display:block;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Let me know if you were able to make this work.

Cheers